# Plot RGB map from three columns of data using Matplotlib

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib, rgb

Is it possible to plot a map of RGB values using Matplotlib?

I have three columns of data that I read from a text file in the following form where x and y are the desired coordinates and z is a hex string of the desired rgb color to plot at the given coordinates:

```
x   y   z 

1  0.5  #000000 

2  0.5  #FF0000 

3  0.5  #00FF00 

1  1.5  #0000FF 

2  1.5  #FFFF00 

3  1.5  #00FFFF 

1  1.5  #FF00FF 

2  2.5  #C0C0C0 

3  2.5  #FFFFFF
```

This is my current state of code. An error is thrown from the griddata() function:

```
import pandas as pds
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import text file using pandas
datafile = pds.read_csv(PathToData,sep='\t')

X=datafile.x
Y=datafile.y
Z=datafile.z

# Generate mesh as 'numpy.ndarray' type for plotting
# This throws the following error:
# ValueError: could not convert string to float: #FFAA39
Z=griddata(X, Y, Z, unique(X), unique(Y))
```

Many thanks

Comment: It is possible, but what have you tried?

Comment: I have been experimenting with pcolor() and imshow() but neither seem to be working correctly for me at the moment. Thanks

Comment: You should post your attempts.  People are much more willing to help you fix code you already have than flat out write code for you.  Is your problem you can't parse the text file?  If not, we don't need to know you are importing from a text file once you have the data in arrays.  Is `imshow` giving you errors? If so what errors? If not, what is it doing (or not doing) that is different from your expectations?

Comment: please help us to help you

Comment: I have added some code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`griddata` is a function for interpolating unevenly spaced data on to a grid ([griddata doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html)).  In your case, it looks like you *already* have data on a grid, you just need to reshape it.  The error you are getting arises because `griddata` is trying to convert you color hex codes to floats for the interpolation, which you *should* be getting because there is not a sensible float interpertation of `#00FF00`.

```
data_dims = (3, 3) # or what ever your data really is
X = np.asarray(x).reshape(data_dims)
Y = np.asarray(y).reshape(data_dims)
C = np.asarray([mpl.colors.colorConverter.to_rgb(_hz) for _hz in z]).reshape(data_dims + (3,)) 
# the colors converted to (r, g, b) tuples
```

The `asarray` calls are to make sure we have arrays, not data frames.

If you just want to see the array we can use `imshow` to plot it:

```
imshow(c, interpolation='none', 
       origin='bottom', 
       extent=[np.min(X), np.max(X), np.min(Y), np.max(Y)])
```

[color converter doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.ColorConverter), [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) doc.

You might need to transpose/flip/rotate `C` to get the orientation you expect.

Comment: Thanks. That is almost perfect, however, axis numbering is a little bit off... is there a simple way to fix that? Here is a link to the output [link](http://i45.tinypic.com/2m4x2cy.png)

Comment: play with the values in `extent`.  That box is the box that the result will fill.